# vuejs - How to remove hash from url using vue-router in Laravel without requesting to server again?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to remove hash(#) from url in vuejs using vue-router in Laravel. So I used `mode:'history'` or `history: true`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: routes,
    mode: 'history'
    //history: true
});
```

and it works perfectly but the problem is that each time request is changed for example from `example.com/home` to `example.com/user` the request will be sent to server and all the page will be refreshed however I want to only change the content between head and foot of the page. So when I mark an string in the top menu it will not unmarked when going to another url but now it sends the server and the page loads completely when not using `mode:'hash'`.

How can I remove hash without sending another request to server in order not to load the page again completely and load only body part?

Thanks

Comment: can you share how you create the links? according to the doc *"In HTML5 history mode, router-link will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't try to reload the page."*

Comment: @Daniel I don't have created links yet I just change it manually in url. If you are saying that doesn't work manually so why it works with `mode: 'hash'`? So if router-link works just like that I should use it I think. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have created links yet I just change it manually in url. If you are saying that doesn't work manually so why it works with mode: 'hash'? So if router-link works just like that I should use it I think. I didn't know about that

ok… I get it

if you are using history mode, you **have to** use `<route-link>` because, as noted above,

> In HTML5 history mode, router-link will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't try to reload the page.

When you enter a new url, the browser loads that page, that's the browser's way of operating and you can't get around that. The framework however handler it differently, by updating the url and the content, but not *actually* redirecting(reloading)

The reason why this works with the hashbang, is that the broser treats everything after the `#` character as in-page navigation. Meaning it doesn't consider it as a redirect. The hash character was traditionally used in HTML to allow navigate to items within a page.

For example, `about-us.html#contact` redirects a user to the about page and scrolls to the contact form.

The modern js frameworks use the hash to hack this navigation by not redirecting, and using the content after the hash to pass routes.

For example, if you have a route such as `localhost:8080/#/about-us`, the `localhost:8080/#` part is the same as `localhost:8080/index.html#` so changing anything after the `#` character keeps the browser on the same page, and the javascript (vue router) handles any changes that are needed.

Hope this clears it up. Fwiw, I haven't used history mode on any of my projects.